# Mock environment variables in ASP.NET Core development

Tags: asp.net

I want to mock environment variables in an ASP.NET development environment. I'd like to know if there is a way that will work both in development and production environment without the need of specific code.

So for example I want to store the db connection string for development in a separate file that will not be committed through version control but at the same time i'd like for it to be available using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` so that it will also read actual environment variables in production.

I've tried using `builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile()` but then I'd need to read secrets from `Configuration` which is not where environment variables will be.